# missing notification popups from Spotify in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, notification, spotify

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Before the upgrade, Spotify would send a notification whenever it started playing a track, causing a notification popup to appear just under the clock. After the upgrade, Spotify still sends a notification (as evidenced by the bell icon beside the clock, and the notification text if I click on the clock), but the popup doesn't appear. Is there some way to make the popup appear?

Note that notification popups from other applications (e.g., Slack) *do* appear.

"Do Not Disturb" is disabled.

gsettings says "org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners true".

Spotify version is 1.1.84.716.gc5f8b819, which is latest/stable.
GNOME appears to be 42.4-0.

---

A few weeks later: I just discovered that desktop notifications have an associated urgency level (low, normal, or critical). Experimenting with the `notify-send` command, it appears that Gnome handles "low" urgency by not showing the popup.

So the problem might be that Spotify is sending the "next track" notification at low urgency, whereas I'd prefer normal urgency. But I don't know if there's any way to persuade it to do so.

---

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Notifications-Bug-Linux-Desktop-Gnome/td-p/5397421 is a bug report at Spotify for the same bug. It suggests that the problem is in Gnome 42.

Comment: Your last edit should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a nice alternative https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4472/spotify-tray/